# Python - Modifying existing excel using Pandas and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an Excel file (`Celebrities.xlsx`) with multiple sheets and I'm trying to modify a single sheet called `Relationships` without modifying (or potentially erasing) other sheets. Here's what I've done.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# Name of the celebrity that I want to modify
celeb_name = 'Terence Stamp'

wb = load_workbook('Celebrities.xlsx')
ws = wb['Relationships']

df = pd.read_excel('Celebrities.xlsx', sheet_name='Relationships')

# This part is trivial, but basically I'm replacing every null cell in 'Link' column with the word 'empty' (of that particular celebrity)
df.loc[(df['Celebrity Name'] == celeb_name) & (df['Link'].isnull()), 'Link'] = 'empty'

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save('new.xlsx')
```

Now the script runs without any error and `new.xlsx` is created successfully, but when I try to open it, it gives me this error:

> Warning loading document new.xlsx: The data could not be loaded
>   completely because the maximum number of rows per sheet was exceeded.

And nothing has been modified!

I can assure that this part of the code works perfectly:

```
wb = load_workbook('Celebrities.xlsx')
ws = wb['Relationships']
wb.save('new.xlsx')
```

I suppose the problem is with this part of code:

```
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There is no point in using both `load_workbook()` and `pandas.read_excel()` on the same file.

Comment: You probably don't want to use append here but overwrite the exsiting cells.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yes, using both was confusing to me too. However, there's something that I use from each of them; I use DataFrame from `Pandas` and I modify the file with `openpyxl`.

Comment: @CharlieClark How can I overwrite the existing cells? That is, indeed, what I wanted to do initially.

Comment: Rewrite your question to make it clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say in your question *nothing has been modified*. But it has. Your code is looping through the dataframe and adding a new row to the worksheet each time through the loop. The limit is 1,048,576 rows and Excel is telling you that the modified worksheet exceeds that limit.

Comment: You're right, it **has** been modified. I wanted to overwrite the existing cells.

Comment: Matching the dataframe to the worksheet to do the update in place might be tricky. One solution would be to add a new empty worksheet to the workbook to hold the modified data, and populate that using `ws.append()`. But do you really need a dataframe at all? Why not modify the worksheet directly?

Comment: sorry for the delay! I use `Pandas` because of its flexibility and that I can do rather complicated things (like the code above) with it, and it's just easy to use. I didn't know how to save the modified `DataFrame` (while preserving formatting and not changing other contents (such as other sheets)), so I turned to `openpyxl`, which does this perfectly, but then I don't know how to do the complicated modifying with `openpyxl` (that I did with `Pandas`). Hope I explained it well!

Comment: To get your approach to work, get `openpyxl` to delete all the rows in the worksheet (`ws.delete_rows()`) before adding them all back again from `pandas` with `ws_append()`. Though the sheer inefficiency of that makes me cringe. I think you would be better off learning how to loop through the rows of `ws` and modifying them directly. I reckon it shouldn't be more than 4 lines of code. And with either approach, do yourself a favour: make a small abridged version of your workbook instead of testing your code using one that has more than half a million rows in it.